# Android NavController: How to solve saveBackStack must not contain retained fragment

Tags: android, navigation, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I am trying create deeplinks to specific screens via incoming push notifications on our Android app by calling `NavController.handleDeeplink(intent)`.

But when the app tries to navigate to the specific Fragment an exceptionis thrown:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: saveBackStack("95f6209a-b0e7-46f9-a37e-6c01ee5fb1fc") must not contain retained fragments. Found direct reference to retained fragment xxxFragment{a0041f} (f8f7126e-5402-4ab2-b14f-7a656480d3f7 id=0x7f0a03a5)

Anyone any pointers on how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

In my case used Fragments in the app where inhereting from a BaseFragment that where calling the deprecated:

> setRetainInstance(true);

Removing this solved it.